# How to set configuration properties in VS once and for all?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

In VS 2010RC I have to specify configuration properties and specifically included path every time I'm creating new project. Is there a way to do it just once for all future projects?
I'm asking this for a reason that I'm starting to use Boost libraries and I have to specify all those paths every time I'm creating project which is bit tedious.

Comment: I agree this really sucks but I don't see how it can be done otherwise with the move to MSBuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VC++ Directories (which is what I think you're looking to configure) have been moved to a property sheet to make them more MSBuild-friendly.

A snippet from http://blogs.msdn.com/vsproject/archive/2009/07/07/vc-directories.aspx:

> If you open up the Property Manager view to see the property sheets associated with your project, you’ll see that one of the property sheets is named `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.User`. This property sheet is actually stored in `LocalAppData`, just as `VCComponents.dat` file was, in the directory `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0`. Using the property editor on the property sheet (just right-click on this property sheet node and select Properties…), you can see that you are able to make edits directly to this file. Since all projects, by default, import this property sheet, you are effectively editing the VC++ directories in the same way you were able to do before.

See the following for more details on property sheets in VC++ 2010:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/vsproject/archive/2009/06/23/inherited-properties-and-property-sheets.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I usually copy the `*.vcproj` and `*.sln` files and then edit them, changing files and project names.  If you create projects frequently, you may want to copy the files, edit them to the bare minimum and save as read-only stencils.